# Total torque about any line when resultant force is zero

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

While reading about rotational equilibrium in a book, I came across a statement which I was unable to understand:

> In general,
> the torque is different about different lines but it can be shown that if the resultant force is zero, the total torque about any line perpendicular to the plane of the forces is equal. If it is zero about one such line, it will
> be zero about all such lines.

My questions are:

1. How do we show the truth of the statement, i.e. how do we prove it.
2. Why is it only same about any `perpendicular line` to the plane. I hope the proof itself  will be able to help me understand this question.

Comment: Could you tell us what exactly you don't understand about the statement?

Comment: how we can arrive to the statement...

Comment: plane of the forces means the plane that is parallel to the forces creating the torque.

Comment: line perpendicular to the plane of forces means the rotating axis.

Comment: Possible duplicate :  Is the moment of a force the same about any point? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109310

Answer (score 4):

The total torque about some axis is defined as: $\vec{\tau}_\text{tot}=\Sigma \left(\vec{r}_i \times{}\vec{f}_i\right) $

If you change to a parallel axis located $\vec{r}$ away from the first one on the plane of the forces, the new torque will be:  $$\vec{\tau}_\text{tot}'=\Sigma \left[(\vec{r}_i+\vec{r}) \times{}\vec{f}_i\right] =\vec{\tau}_\text{tot}+\vec{r}\times{}\Sigma  \vec{f}_i=\vec{\tau}_\text{tot}$$

As $\Sigma  \vec{f}_i=\vec 0$